# Is it possible to change the coding conventions in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I want to change the way that Visual Studio generates the coding template for a WinForms application.

For example in C#:

1. Once I drag and drop a control on the designer, the name of this control will be in *CamelCase*
2. Once I define the control event, Visual Studio generates the code as *CamelCase* then "_" then the event name in *pascalCase*

What I want is to tell Visual Studio to use *pascalCase* in all cases. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm curious to see if there is, in fact, a way to change this.

Comment: You can simply rename the controls. Which you should do anyway, because the auto-generated names aren't really meaningful.

Comment: Dirk hit it right on. My question is why would you want to change the camel case naming convention? Generally you want to stick with the language standards.

Comment: @Dirk most of the controls if they are not in camel case, no need to rename them, and about the numbers generated by the visual studio for each control, i am replacing them using find regular expression, also for the event generated, i would like to let the visual studio not to add the _

Comment: @kinezu I am wondering if possible to change this like many settings in visual studio, like the adding of new class, we can control the code generated, we can change the menu texts from capital to normal, ... etc

Comment: It's not trivial, but you might check out this doc on customizing code generation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973818.aspx

Comment: I spent more than 3 days searching about such configurations in Visual Studio, it seems that you can't change these conventions.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with your own controls using the `DesignerSerializer` attribute and providing your own `CodeDomSerializer`, but no, there's no Visual Studio option or a way to hook up the designer to change the serialization for all/built-in controls.